# Django update template image after save it on server storage

Tags: django, image, django-templates

I have a question about file upload and refresh it on template.
I have a custom variation of file saving system in my view:

```
sp = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../media/avatars')
av_name = os.path.join(sp, u.username + "_avatar.jpg") 
dataUrlPattern = re.compile('data:image/(png|jpeg);base64,(.*)$')
ImageData = request.POST.get('u_avatar')
ImageData = dataUrlPattern.match(ImageData).group(2)
ImageData = base64.b64decode(ImageData)
ava = open(av_name, 'wb')
ava.write(ImageData)
ava.close()
```

And it works fine. I can upload and update avatars and save it with a custom name in media folder. But when I try to save a new file, it doesn't refresh on template! I mean that file saved correctly, I see a new image in server folder, but template render old version of them. When I try to open a image link, I still see an old file.

I think the reason is some kind of cache, but I can't understand, how it works.

Could you, please, help me, how I can refresh image after each upload?

**EDIT:**

This is my complete view:

```
def edit(request):
u = request.user
p = get_object_or_404 (Profile, user=request.user)
if request.method == 'POST':
    profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
    if profile_form.is_valid():
        if request.POST.get('u_avatar'):
            sp = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../media/avatars')
            av_name = os.path.join(sp, u.username + "_avatar.jpg")
            os.remove(av_name)
            dataUrlPattern = re.compile('data:image/(png|jpeg);base64,(.*)$')
            ImageData = request.POST.get('u_avatar')
            ImageData = dataUrlPattern.match(ImageData).group(2)
            ImageData = base64.b64decode(ImageData)
            ava = open(av_name, 'wb')
            ava.write(ImageData)
            ava.close()
        profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = u
        profile.avatar = str("/media/avatars/" + u.username + "_avatar.jpg")
        profile.filled = True
        if p.rate < 0.5:
            profile.rate = 0.5
        else:
            profile.rate = p.rate
        profile.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('profile')
else:
    profile_form = ProfileForm()
return render(request, 'profile_edit.html', {'profile_form': profile_form})
```

And this is my avatar on template:

```
<div class="lavatar"><a href="/profile"><img src="{{ user.profile.avatar }}" class="img-circle"></a></div>
```

BTW, I use CharField for avatar instead of ImageField or FileField. Maybe problem with that.

**EDIT2**

Now I found a new interesting fact: the image is updated after some time. I uploaded a new image and didn't touch site about 1,5 - 2 hours. And avatar had refreshed.

Comment: Have you implemented view or template caching? Have you cleared your browser's cache? Are you using a cached_property on your model to display the image? Have you tested that you code is actually updating the file as you expect it to? What have you tried to debug the issue?

Comment: Set django.middleware.cache.CacheMiddleware' and CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = 0 - NOTHING.

Comment: That doesn't actually answer my question. Are you caching the view? The template? The property?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have time to finish. Set django.middleware.cache.CacheMiddleware' and CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = 0 - NOTHING. Removed Chrome cache - NOTHING. System works well at first time, but if I want to change avatar, it changes only in server folder. And I'm not using cache anywhere.

Comment: Can you please add your template and view code that displays the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a problem!

Cloudflare! I set "Bypass cache" on a page rule and it seems to work well.